# How to add end of a object group in ArrayList containing different objects

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I'm supposed to create an `addcourse` method to an `ArrayList`.
`Arraylist` has students and courses. Courses are added after the student and to the end of that student. For example, an `Arraylist` can contain `(Student1, Course1, Course2, Student2, Course1, Course3)`. When I want to add `Course3` to `Student1` it should go after `Course2`, but before `Student2`.

The `addcourse` method should have the interface:
`void addcourse(Student s, Course c).`
First choosing the student that I want to add course to and which course. How can I find the index of `Student2` in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: This doesn't related to Android at all. P. S. list.add(list.indexOf(*where to place*), *element*)

Comment: [This](https://dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and) is exactly what you need. It uses a HashMap to store multiple values (in your case Course) under one key (in your case Student).

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari Couldn't he just put an `ArrayList<Course>` in each Student object?

Comment: You are right but I m expected to do this in a different class in addcourse method.No changes available for student class

Comment: @ArjunPanickssery Yes that is possible, but then in case items are added/ removed in between or at the beginning of the list, item indexes will change, then using HashMap he can still do a key lookup but using ArrayList he will have to iterate over the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the `ArrayList` for? You can just add an `ArrayList<Course> courses` to the Student class.

Ex:

```
public class Student{
    public ArrayList<Course> courses = new Arraylist<Course>;

    //Other stuff

    public void addCourse(Course c){
        courses.add(c);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since this won't work for the OP, I have also included a method that works within the constraints of the problem. The steps:

- Find the index of the `Student`
- Find the index of the *next* `Student`
- Place the new `Course` right before the next `Student`

If your ArrayList is called `list`, then something like this would work:

```
    public void addCourse(Student student, Course course){
        int studentIndex = -1;
        int nextStudentIndex = -1;

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            if(!(list.get(i) instanceof Student)){
                continue;
            }

            if(list.get(i).equals(student)){
                studentIndex = i;
                continue;
            }

            if(studentIndex != -1 && nextStudentIndex == -1){
                nextStudentIndex = i;
            }
        }

        list.add(nextStudentIndex, course);
    }
```

Comment: You are right but I m expected to do this in a different class in addcourse method.No changes available for student class

Comment: @elliotaks I made an edit. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Good job but there is a slight problem.it gives like course couse student course course student.Should be like student course student course

Comment: I don't understand. Could you give an example of an input that you tried, and what the output was?

Comment: For example I add Student1,then Student2.The using your method I add Course1 and Course2 to arraylist.then using method I add course3 and course4 for student2.and output is : course1,course2,student1,course3,course4,student2:

Comment: but it should be : student1,course1,course2,student2,course1,course2

Comment: It's possible that I misunderstood the question. If you pass addCourse(student1, course4), shouldn't it add course4 to the list? Or should the courses always be numbered starting from 1?

Comment: It should add the course to the list.but in your method it always add before the normal student not nextstudent.

Comment: Thank you. I see the problem now. The new version should work correctly.